# How to change the src of images which has no class/ID from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, src

I would like to change the source of the `img` from JavaScript by using Ajax. And `img` tag does not have any IDs or classes, and I cannot figure out how to select the `img` and how to change the `src`. How can I do that? I put part of my HTML (it is provided, and so I cannot modify) and part of my JavaScript. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="moves">
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">Move Name Here</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
        var moveArr = data.moves;
        var moves = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
        for(var x=0; x < data.moves.length; x++){
            moves[x].innerHTML = moveArr[x].name;
            img[x].src = "icons\/" + moveArr[x].type + ".jpg"; // I cannot write this part correctly.
        }
```

Comment: Which image do you want to change? And can you modify the html at all?

Comment: I cant modify the html at all. And I want to change all the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you don't have a reference to the image that you are trying to change the src of.  I would do:

```
var moveArr = data.moves;
var moves = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
for(var x=0; x < data.moves.length; x++){
    moves[x].innerHTML = moveArr[x].name;
    var img = moves[x].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    img.src = "icons\/" + moveArr[x].type + ".jpg";
}
```

If the layout of your page changes you might have to alter this code.  Should work for what you have now, though.

Comment: Thank you so much. This code works properly. Why do I have to put [0] after getElementsByTagName('img'), and what does it mean??

Comment: Because there can be more than one img inside any given element, getElementsByTagName returns a nodelist.  So we're using the first image in that list (ie [0]).

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

If each `span` is succeeded by an `img` (as it appears to be from the code you've posted) so there's the same number of `.move` items and images -- and they match up -- then you can use the [DOM images collection](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_images.asp) to target each image's `src`, like so:

```
    var moveArr = data.moves;
    var moves = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
    for(var x = 0; x < data.moves.length; x++){
        moves[x].innerHTML = moveArr[x].name;
        document.images[x].src = "icons\/" + moveArr[x].type + ".jpg";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But it did not work properly. I think that' because I have other img tags in the rest of my HTML, and other images are also changed from your suggested code... I would like to change images only under the class "move"

Comment: @AndyAnderson Ah okay. If you know how many images you have before the images mentioned here, just add that number. For example, if you have 5 images preceeding your images that you want to change, modify `document.images[x].src` to `document.images[5 + x].src` instead.

Comment: Oh I got it! That works! Thank you for your comment!